# SharePoint 2007: Page is checked out by another user. How can I force an end to the check-out?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, versioning

A page has been checked out by someone who I am not able to contact. I need to update the page but cannot check it out until the current check-out is finished.

How can I force the current check-out to be discarded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have administrative rights, it is possible to override the check-out via the View All Site Content page:

1. Site Actions
2. View All Site Content
3. Pages
4. Hover the item you want to
   check out, and from the context-menu
   (arrow-down next to the filename),
   choose "Discard Check Out"

It is also possible to perform this routine through SharePoint Designer.